# Parsing a page, getting the contents of an input field?

Tags: php, scrape

I want to open a page using PHP, and get two values from two input fields.

The input fields are like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__ONE" id="__ONE" value="/randomletters" />  
<input type="hidden" name="__TWO" id="__TWO" value="/randomletters" />
```

How would I be able to go about doing this?

Scraping this page, and returning the value for `input "__ONE" as $one`, and so on...

Comment: Is the plan to open an existing html (or other) document without actually serving it, say with fopen or equiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML parser. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ is one example.

```
$html = file_get_html('mydocument.html');
$values = array();
foreach($html->find('input') as $element)
{
    $values[$element->id] = $element->value;
}

print_r( $values );
```

...

```
Array
(
    [__ONE] => /randomletters
    [__TWO] => /randomletters
)
```

You could also try [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) or [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or Zend Framework, etc, etc. They're all good.

Also, I would like to congratulate you for being the first person ever on stackoverflow NOT to start off by asking how you can accomplish this with regular expressions. :)